# Csv file read into issues

Tags: r, dataframe

I don't understand why when I read into a `csv.`  file, when the first column name is empty, is filed in with `X1` as well there is an index column at beginning of my data. How can I avoid this?

Data structure:

[image]

Desired output:
[image]

sample data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(110, 210, 310, 1110, 3110, 5310, 8210, 
9120, 9390), `110` = c(0.970588235, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 
0), `210` = c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0), `310` = c(0.029411765, 
0.25, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.981481481, 
0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0), `3110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.25, 
0, 0, 0.037037037), `5310` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0, 0.037037037
), `8210` = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.875, 0, 0), `9120` = c(0, 
0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0), `9390` = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0.018518519, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.925925926)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `8210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9120` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9390` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `row.names = 1` while reading so that it will return with the first column as row names

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks it ignores the first column but all the column names received an X in the front. Can this be removed?

Comment: @user10974052 I am guessin g that you read with `read_csv` instead of `read.csv`.  With `read.csv`, by default `check.names = TRUE` which can be changed to `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Second option is to specify the colnames through col.names or other package equivalent

```
library(data.table) 

df <- fread("df.csv",
        header = TRUE,
        col.names = c("","110","210","310","1110","3110","5310","8210","9120","9390"))
```